# Python extract a week number from the specific date

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to extract a week number from a data in panda dataframe but starting from the SPECIFIC date.

For example from 4th April:

`20/04/2010 --> 1`

`27/04/2010 --> 2`

`04/05/2010 --> 3`

and so on..

Any idea?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you can try getting the day count from the beginning of that year and divide it by 7. I'm not sure whether it will always give the right number.

Comment: Does the week begin at the specified date or at the first day of the week of the specified date?

Comment: It begins at the specified date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just calculate the difference in days between 2 dates, divide by 7 and add 1 :

```
from datetime import date

origin = date(2010, 4, 20)

def week_number_from(my_date, origin):
    return (my_date - origin).days / 7 + 1
```

Comment: @Giada if this answers your question, consider upvoting the answer and selecting it as your chosen answer by clicking the green check.

Answer (score 1):

Use pandas to_datetime to parse your date column if it is not already in datetime format.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html

Then use the date time method weekday.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

```
my_dataframe['week_nums'] = pandas.to_datetime(my_dataframe['date_col']).weekday()
```

Sorry I saw you want week day from specific date, will update answer... it is easy to calculate the difference between 2 dates.

Comment: Thanks! But this shows a week number starting from the 1st January..  :/